# Get increasing loss and poor performance on Variational Autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I'm a beginner of neural network and currently working on using neural network to analyze protein sequence alignment data. The data is converted to one-hot encoding binary data. I'm using keras to build my variational autoencoder. My model has 4 "Dense" layers for both encoder and decoder. The input is normalized by "BatchNormalization" and Dropout layer is also added inside the model. The optimizer is Adam. The problem is I get very huge and still increasing loss, and they soon reach nan. I try to use learning rate = 0.1, 0.2 or 0.8 and use decay to reduce the learning rate. But it doesn't help. I'm stuck on this model for a week...almost collapse. Thanks for any help!

```
x = Input(shape=(original_dim,))
dr = Dropout(0.7)
h1z = BatchNormalization(mode = 0)(x)
h1 = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='elu')(h1z)
h2 = dr(Dense(intermediate_dim2, activation='elu')(h1))
h3 = Dense(intermediate_dim3, activation = 'elu')(h2)
h4 = Dense(intermediate_dim4, activation = 'elu')(h3)

z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h4)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim)(h4)

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], latent_dim), 
             mean=0.,stddev=epsilon_std)
return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var / 2) * epsilon

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_var])
decoder_h4 = Dense(intermediate_dim4, activation = 'elu')
decoder_h3 = Dense(intermediate_dim3, activation='elu')
decoder_h2 = Dense(intermediate_dim2, activation='elu')
decoder_h1 = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='elu')
drd = Dropout(0.7)  
decoder_mean = Dense(original_dim, activation='sigmoid')

h_decoded4 = BatchNormalization(mode = 0)(decoder_h4(z))
h_decoded3 = decoder_h3(h_decoded4)
h_decoded2 = drd(decoder_h2(h_decoded3))
h_decoded1 = decoder_h1(h_decoded2)
x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(h_decoded1)

def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
    xent_loss = original_dim * metrics.binary_crossentropy(x,
           x_decoded_mean)
    kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - 
            K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
    return K.mean(xent_loss + kl_loss)

vae = Model(x, x_decoded_mean)
vae.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr = 0, decay = 0), loss=vae_loss, metrics= 
      `enter code here`["categorical_accuracy","top_k_categorical_accuracy"])
```

Comment: share your code - in its most compact form

Comment: code is shared above :D

Comment: Generally, 0.1 is a very high learning rate for Adam. The default is 0.001 for a reason.

Comment: And maybe lower your dropout to 0.1 and increase it step by step.